# Как из подфункции вывести переменную в функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
var flag = true;                                                            
 $(window).resize(function () {                                             
     if ($(window).width()<748){                                            
        flag=false;                                                         
}                                                                           
    });                                                                     

console.log(flag);                                                          

    if(flag === true) {                                                     

        $(function () {                                                     
            $('nav div>ul>li').hover(function () {                          
                $(this).children('ul').stop(false, true).fadeIn(1000);      
            }, function () {                                                
                $(this).children('ul').stop(false, true).fadeOut(1000);     
            });                                                             

        })                                                                  
    }                                                                       
        else                                                                
            {                                                               
        $(function () {                                                     
         $('nav div>ul>li').click(function() {                              
             $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);                    
         });                                                                
        });                                                                 
    }                                                                       
});
```

Собственно трабл в том что я не знаю как сделать чтобы flag работал и выводился наружу из функции и становился переменной функции.
console.log() всегда выдает true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменную `flag` надо использовать внутри обработчиков `hover` и `click`, а не снаружи.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var flag = true;                                                            
  $(window).resize(function () {                                             
    flag = $(window).width() >= 748;
  });                                                                     

  $('nav div>ul>li').hover(function () {
    if (flag) {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, true).fadeIn(1000);
    }
  }, function () {                                                
    if (flag) {
      $(this).children('ul').stop(false, true).fadeOut(1000);
    }
  });                                                             

  $('nav div>ul>li').click(function() {
    if (!flag) {
      $(this).find("ul").stop().slideToggle(300);
    }
  });  
});
```

Или

Подсоединять/отсоединять обработчики `hover` и `click` внутри обработчика `resize`.

Comment: Спасибо. Не порекомендуете почитать(посмотреть) что нибудь чтобы этой темой овладеть подосканальнее?

Comment: @rodion080 В первую очередь https://api.jquery.com/ . Но в данном случае, нужно всего лишь задуматься над последовательностью событий в коде. Значение переменной `flag` будет присвоено только в момент изменения размеров окна, так что строить логику действий в зависимости от этого значения внутри `$(document).ready` - слишком рано. Слева от ответа - галочка. Успехов.